# Problems with Date format in elasticsearch.net and Nest (C#)

Tags: c#, datetime, elasticsearch, date-format, nest

I have the following C# model :

```
[ElasticType(Name = "myType")]
public class MyType
{
    ...
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "ElasticId")]
    [DataMember(Name = "ElasticId")]
    public string ElasticId { get; set; }
    ...
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "DateToBeUsed", Type = FieldType.Date, DateFormat = "date_hour_minute_second_millis")]
    public string DateToBeUsed { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The "date_hour_minute_second_millis" correspond to following format : yyyy-MM-dd’T'HH:mm:ss.SSS
(http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html)

The mapping ES is done with Nest using "map" method and correspond to that :

```
"mappings": {
     "myType": {
        "properties": {
            ...,
            "ElasticId": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            ...,
            "DateToBeUsed": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "date_hour_minute_second_millis"
            },
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I insert an document inside this index:

```
"_source": {
        ...,
        "ElasticId": "2",
        ...,
        "DateToBeUsed": "2012-05-21T09:51:34.073",
        ...
        }
```

My problem is when I want to retrieve this object through Nest.

The value of DateToBeUsed is always formatted with the following format : MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
(ex : 05/21/2012 09:51:34)

(Using sense, the value is well formatted.)

1°) Is this normal?

I need to retrieve the same date format than the one I gave to ES. 
(And I think it should be normal to have the same format as described in the mapping)

2°) Is there a "clean" solution to resolve this problem? 
(Re-formatting the date after having retrieved the document is not a "clean" solution...)

Thanks for the answers!
Bye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce what you're seeing, using the following code, but the date value is being returned in the `Get` call as expected:

```cs
string indexName = "so-27927069";

// --- create index ---
client.CreateIndex(cid => cid.Index(indexName));
Console.WriteLine("created index");

// --- define map ---
client.Map<MyType>(m => m
    .Index(indexName)
    .Type("myType")
    .MapFromAttributes());
Console.WriteLine("set mapping");

// ---- index -----
client.Index<MyType>(
    new MyType
    {
        DateToBeUsed = new DateTime(2012, 5, 21, 9, 51, 34, 73)
            .ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fff"),
        ElasticId = "2"
    },
    i => i
        .Index(indexName)
        .Type("myType")
        .Id(2)
);
Console.WriteLine("doc indexed");

// ---- get -----
var doc = client.Get<MyType>(i => i
        .Index(indexName)
        .Type("myType")
        .Id(2)
    );

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("doc.Source.DateToBeUsed: ");
Console.WriteLine(doc.Source.DateToBeUsed);
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("doc.RequestInformation.ResponseRaw: ");
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(doc.RequestInformation.ResponseRaw));
```

I'm seeing the following result as output:

```
created index
set mapping
doc indexed

doc.Source.DateToBeUsed:
2012-05-21T09:51:34.073

doc.RequestInformation.ResponseRaw:
{"_index":"so-27927069","_type":"myType","_id":"2","_version":1,"found":true,"_source":{
  "ElasticId": "2",
  "DateToBeUsed": "2012-05-21T09:51:34.073"
}}
```

(Watching the traffic via [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), I'm seeing an exact match between the `ResponseRaw` value and the payload of the response to the `Get` request.)

I'm on Elasticsearch version 1.5.2 and NEST version 1.6.0.  (Maybe the issue you were seeing was fixed sometime in the interim....)

Comment: Thanks for the answer:)
I was on NEST 1.4.1 and ES 1.4.x.. Maybe the issue is resolved or maybe I was doing something wrong..
Anyway, thanks :)